# Generating XYZ tiles in nodejs

Tags: gdal2tiles, xyz, node-js

I'm looking to create XYZ tiles for use in leafletjs with nodejs. Previously I've been creating my tiles using this [python library](https://github.com/commenthol/gdal2tiles-leaflet) (gdal2tiles).

I was wondering if anyone had yet written a nodejs equivalent?

I'm looking to take a single png image and specify the zoom range for the tiles to generated at, min zoom probably defined by `log2(max(width, height)/tilesize)`

Ideally each zoom range could be created by an independent process as I'd like to spin up a separate AWS lambda instance for each zoom level and upload the tiles to an S3 bucket in parallel.

How do I generate these tiles in JS rather than Python where I lack the knowledge to edit?

Comment: I am looking for something similar. Did you ever get around to solving this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I resorted to modifying my previous gdal2tiles script in python

Answer (score 2):

I was able to create this in PHP using the following pseudo code

```
load source image

for each zoom level (0-maxZoom) as zoomLevel
    resize source image based on current zoomLevel pow(2, 8 + zoomLevel)

    while xCoordPointer < resized image size

        while yCoordPointer <= resized image size

            crop resized image at current xCoordPointer, yCoordPointer at 256 x 256

            save in path format /zoomLevel/xCount/yCount.png

            increment yCoordPointer + 256
            increment yCount + 1

        reset yCoordPonter = 0
        reset yCount = 0

        increment xCoordPointer + 256
        increment xCount + 1
```

maxZoom calculated by

```
ceil(log(max(originalImageWidth, originalImageHeight) / 256, 2))
```

I attempted it in Node.js but unfortunately every library I tried choked on the very large image source (~80MB)